# Get attribute of relationship nodes in Neo4j using Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I use Neo4jClient and I want to get relation attribute `MATCH (n:Users {id:1})-[r]-(m:Users) RETURN r` how I can get node with attribute relation , for example :

```
Node[0]{id:1,name:"Oliver Stone"}
Node[1]{id:2,name:"Charlie Sheen"}
Node[2]{id:3,name:"Martin Sheen"}
Node[3]{id:4,name:"TheAmericanPresident"}
```

> I should know , what is attribute relation between Node[0] and  Node[2]? (attribute mean "FOLLOW" or "IGNORE")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the `TypeKey` from the `r` value you are also retrieving:

```
var query = Client.Cypher
    .Match("(n:User)-[r]-(m:User)")
    .Where((UserEntity n) => n.Id == 1)
    .Return((n, r, m) => new
    {
        N = n.As<UserEntity>(),
        M = m.As<UserEntity>(),
        R = r.As<RelationshipInstance<object>>()
    });

var res = query.Results;
foreach (var item in res.ToList())
    Console.WriteLine("({0})-[:{1}]-({2})", item.N.Id, item.R.TypeKey, item.M.Id);
```

You'll obviously need to change `UserEntity` for whatever your type actually is.

Comment: thanks a lot ... how I can use that for `MATCH (n:Users {id:1})-[r:FOLLOW*1..4]-(m:Users)`

Comment: Hi @Amirhosseingholzam, Please ask as a new question.

Comment: new question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25801597/get-relationship-nodes-by-variable-length-relationships-in-neo4j-using-neo4jclie