# Get relationship nodes by Variable length relationships in Neo4j using Neo4jClient

Tags: c#, .net, neo4j, neo4jclient

I use Neo4jClient and I want to get relation attribute  by Variable length relationships `(n:Users {id:1})-[r:FOLLOW*1..4]-(m:Users) RETURN r` how I can get node with attribute relation , for example :

```
Node[0]{id:1,name:"Oliver Stone"}
Node[1]{id:2,name:"Charlie Sheen"}
Node[2]{id:3,name:"Martin Sheen"}
Node[3]{id:4,name:"TheAmericanPresident"}
```

`I should know , what is attribute relation between Node[0] and Node[2]? (attribute mean "FOLLOW" or "IGNORE")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First up, if you are using `[r:FOLLOW*1..4]` you already know the `TypeKey` as it's in your code, *if* you want to get the `TypeKey` for `[r*1..4]` then you can use the below code, the main change is we're bringing back `R` as `IEnumerable<RelationshipInstance<object>>` rather than just straight `RelationshipInstance<object>`.

```
var query = Client.Cypher
    .Match("(n:User)-[r*1..4]-(m:User)")
    .Where((UserEntity n) => n.Id == 1)
    .Return((n, r, m) => new
    {
        N = n.As<UserEntity>(),
        M = m.As<UserEntity>(),
        R = r.As<IEnumerable<RelationshipInstance<object>>>() //<-- IEnumerable<T>
    });

var res = query.Results;

foreach (var item in res.ToList())
    foreach (var relationshipInstance in item.R)
        Console.WriteLine("({0})-[:{1}]-({2})", item.N.Id, relationshipInstance.TypeKey, item.M.Id);
```

Now, imagine you have the following setup:

```
(Node:1)-[:IGNORE]->(Node:2)->(:FOLLOW)->(Node:3)
```

Running the above code will get you this as an output:

```
(1)-[:IGNORE]-(3)
(1)-[:FOLLOW]-(3)
```

You don't *really* know what the order is, and you have conflicting types. Imagining you *are* after the actual route rather than just the names (I realise this may not be the case), we need to change a few more bits of the query.

If you look into the `RelationshipInstance` you are getting back, you'll see it has two properties: `EndNodeReference` and `StartNodeReference`, you'll also note that the `Id` property of those has no relation to any Id you have in your objects. The `Id` in this case relates to the actual Neo4j Id. To get meaningful data out of it, we'll need to get that Id, and that means using `Node<T>`. *Ideally* we don't want to do this, but I'm unaware of any other way to get the routes at the present time.

```
var query = Client.Cypher
    .Match("(n:User)-[r*1..4]-(m:User)")
    .Where((UserEntity n) => n.Id == 1)
    .Return((n, r, m) => new
    {
        N = n.As<Node<UserEntity>>(), //<-- Node<T>
        M = m.As<Node<UserEntity>>(), //<-- Node<T>
        R = r.As<IEnumerable<RelationshipInstance<object>>>()
    });

foreach (var item in res.ToList())
    foreach (var relationshipInstance in item.R)
        Console.WriteLine("({0})-[:{1}]-({2})", item.N.Data.Id, relationshipInstance.TypeKey, item.M.Data.Id);
```

Now you've got all the relevant data for the relationships to piece it all together. If you look at one of the `Node<T>` instances (`N` or `M`), you'll see you have a `.Reference` property which will match to the `.*NodeReference` properties on the `RelationshipInstance`, with that information you can build up the actual `TypeKey` by relation.

Comment: `TData` is whatever your POCO is for a relationship, if you don't have any, then just use `object`. The `NodeId` is the `StartNodeReference` or `EndNodeReference`.